# how to get rid of the time-duration added to rspec when using --out?

Tags: ruby, rspec

When I use `rspec --format documentation` to stdout, I get something like this:

```
User adds a third site and successfully credentials PayPal on FEB-17-2015
      Invoices the customer with a pro-rated Pro plan for the 3 unused days credited (PENDING: Not yet implemented)
```

This is desired behavior.

However, when I use `rspec --format documentation --out spec.txt` I get this:

```
User adds a third site and successfully credentials PayPal on FEB-17-2015
[33m      Invoices the customer with a pro-rated Pro plan for the 3 unused days credited (PENDING: Not yet implemented)[0m
```

The formatting is now unreadable with this addedin `[33m` on one side and `[0m` on the other.

The above behavior runs counter to the example described in the docs:

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-4/docs/command-line/format-option#documentation-format-saved-to-a-file

**Question: How do I make the text match the desired stdout?**

Comment: How do you define unreadable?

Comment: These look like ANSI colour codes, not time duration :) Try disabling colour output on rspec (not sure how to do that).

Comment: Cool, I  looked up colour and found this: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/3447958

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `[33m` is not a time duration; it's an [ANSI color code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) and it's how RSpec prints its output in color.  RSpec is meant to sense that output isn't going to a TTY and disable the color for this case but it appears that's not working.  You can pass `--no-color` to manually disable it, though.

Comment: ah, okay, I also deleted the option from .rspec -- but I guess I could jus add --no-color in the command line, probably a better option